# react-query within a class component where we have send/receive functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I want to use React Query with a specific code structure, and I'd like to know if this is possible for me.

I have a React class component where sending the request and receiving the response are done in separate places

example:

```js
class Engine{

   sendMessage(from, message){
     ...
     // for each subscriber
     subscriber.receive(from, message)
   }

   listenFor(subscriber, chanel){
    ...
   }
}


class ComponentA extends React.Component{
  messageId;

  constructor(props){
   ...
   Engine.listenFor(this, 'APIResponse');
   
   this.state = { data: {} }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
   fetchData();
  }

  fetchData(){
    let msg = createAPIRequestMsg({...});
    this.messageId = msg.id;
    Engine.send(msg);
  }

  recieve(from, message){
    if(message.id == this.messageId){
      let respones = message.response;
      this.setState({ data: response });
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want someway to use `react-query` within this structure, I know we can use it within a class in different ways, but my question is how to use it when the function that is supposed to return a response is not returning the response, for example `fetchData` will not return the response, it will just send a message, and the `receive` function is the one responsible to get the response back, so in this structure we can't use the `fetchData` with `useQuery`, is there a workaround that?